# How to keep .gitignored files off my gh-pages branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

In my global `.gitignore` file I chose to keep my IDE folders out of my versioning. So in my `master` branch are folders like `.idea/` or `*.iml` files. If I now switch to branch `gh-pages` git keeps those IDE specific files and I'm ending up with `/index.html`, `/src/.idea/`, `/sample/.idea/` on that branch even though I don't want the IDE configuration to appear on `gh-pages`.

What's the best way to tell git to drop these files on that branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably `git add`ed those files before setting up the ignore rules. Ignore rules apply to untracked files only; they have no effect on stuff that's already staged/committed.

Given that situation, you can simply make a new commit to get rid of them again:

```
git rm --cached <bad files>
git commit
```

Or you can use [history rewriting](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to get the unwanted files out of the history altogether. Don't do this if other people are already working on the current version of your repo, though.